# Slicing a string from a textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take a string entered by user from a textbox. Check the length of that string and if the string is over a given number perform the slice operation on it.

Here's what I came up with but my code does nothing. Checked console, no errors given.

html:

```
        <form id="slice">
            Enter a pharse:<input type="text" id="text_box_2"><br>

            <input type="button" value="slice" onclick="Slice()">

            Result: <input type="text" id="slice_result"><br>
        </form>
```

Javascript function:

```
function Slice(){
    var UserString = document.getElementById("text_box_2").value;
    var UserStringValue = UserString.length;
    var Result = Userstring.slice(1,6);

    if (UserStringValue > 6){
        document.getElementById("Slice_result").value = Result;
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a longer phrase.")
    }
}
```

what or where did I go wrong?

Comment: Change "Slice_result" to "slice_result" (lowercase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be mindful of case-sensitivity.

This:

```
var Result = Userstring.slice(1,6);
```

Should be using `UserString` (capital "S") as defined earlier in your code.

Next, the input ID should be all lowercase, `slice_result`, to match to HTML, but your code uses different casing:

```
document.getElementById("Slice_result")
```

Here's a [working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dufajiquvu/edit?html,js,console,output) with these fixes.

EDIT: As JaromandaX mentioned in the comments, if you want to take the first 6 characters you should use `slice(0, 6)`.

Comment: to get the first 6 chars, it should be `.slice(0, 6)`

Comment: @ Ahmad Mageed thanks, I had a feeling I  either didn't have it coded correctly or I had been looking at it too long to notice a spelling/name error. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

from cursory reading of your code. it seems caused by this line

```
var Result = Userstring.slice(1,6);
```

and also this one

```
document.getElementById("Slice_result").value = Result
```

it should be

```
var Result = UserString.slice(1,6);
```

and

```
document.getElementById("slice_result").value = Result
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually use of the following

```
var Value = $('#input_id').val();
```

will pull the requested information for you.

You can also set up arguments for your slice function and pass in the value when you run onclick();

I'd also note that slice() is a current js function, though your implentation with the capital 'S' is some what different, it may be better practice to change that name a bit.

Comment: jquery wasn't asked for